# Fullcalendar does not read json

Tags: php, json, wordpress, fullcalendar

I'm making a Wordpress-plugin in which an administrator can add events. Visitors can see a calendar (fullcalendar) where they should see events. However, it does not read the json string which stores all the information. The string looks okay: [{"title":"Evenement01","start":"2013-11-15"},{"title":"Testevenemn12","start":"2013-11-22"}].

Below my json-feed.php code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$rst_events_array = array();
$rst_get_events = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT *
FROM wp_rst_events
");
foreach ($rst_get_events as $val){
    $rst_events_array [] = array(
        'title' => $val->rst_event_name,
        'start' => $val->rst_event_date
    );
}
echo json_encode($rst_events_array);
?>
```

And here my jQuery:

```
jQuery('#rst-calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: 'json-feed.php'

    });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue with Wordpress and needed to add;

```
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    echo event::jsonCalendarEvent($id);
    exit;
```

JSON is very particular and any characters after your echo will kill it on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You should use date/time format as specified in documentation:

> The date/time an event begins. When specifying Event Objects for
>   events or eventSources, you may specify a string in IETF format (ex:
>   "Wed, 18 Oct 2009 13:00:00 EST"), a string in ISO8601 format (ex:
>   "2009-11-05T13:15:30Z") or a UNIX timestamp.

So, in your case:

```
events: [
            {
                "title":"Evenement01",
                "start":"2013-11-15T13:15:30Z"
            },
            {
                "title":"Testevenemn12",
                "start":"2013-11-22T13:15:30Z"
            }
        ]
```

Have a look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cimere/nZRsQ/).
If you want the event lasts all day, you should set the `allDay` properties to `true`.